# Creating Search Engine Friendly URL's with Word Press

Tags: customization, permalinks, plugins, urls

I own a website barrelandblade.com which was developed by a non SEO enlightened developer. I recently had the FV All in One SEO Pack installed as my site does not show up in the search engines at all. I understand my URLs should be representative of my page content but do not know how to go about it.  Is there a way to do this that I can do or have someone setup so my site can get ranked?

Answer (score 3):

A quick lesson in SEO ...

Meta tags, meta keywords, page architecture, and link structure will only get you so far.  It's important to have things set up, yes, but what's more important to search engine rankings is your *content*.

Firstly, your question is slightly misleading.  Your [main site](http://www.barrelandblade.com/index.php) isn't even built on WordPress!  The links throughout that site are references to standard PHP files that I expect are either static files or dynamically generated through some other, non-WordPress CMS.  In any case, *that* is where the URL problem lies.

The actual WordPress site (http://barrelandblade.com/wordpress) has permalinks that are very SEO friendly.  Each post is using WordPress' built-in "pretty permalink" structure, which is built specifically to be SEO, user friendly, and easy to read.  You don't seem to have any WordPress-related SEO problems here.

So to answer your "so my site can get ranked?" question, focus on content.  Build compelling content and get people external to your site to link to it.  *That* will drive traffic and build your Google PageRank (which is what your search engine rankings are based on).

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. It has been a real learning experience and I have a ways to go. I appreciate your time and your help.